# How to use firestore security rules resource.id field?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase security rules come with a resource object that is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource). However using id field while writing rules is not working properly.

```
match /{collectionName}/{document=**} {
            allow read: resource.id == 'SomeDocumentId'
            allow write: if false;
        }

    }
```

When simulated with a document id, it denies.

```
match /{collectionName}/{document=**} {
            allow read: resource.id == null
            allow write: if false;
        }

    }
match /{collectionName}/{document=**} {
            allow read: resource.id != null
            allow write: if false;
        }

    }
```

If you check if it is null or not, both rules always deny. Id field is both null and not null at the same setup.

I believe while writing my rules almost a year before, I tested it and was working but now it is problematic. Any help about using resource.id field?

Comment: One solution is using {document} instead of writing nested rule with {document=**} and using $(document) as a parameter. But I don't want that. I want to use resource.id field.

Comment: What should `allow read: resource.id == null` accomplish? I.e. what read does it allow, and what read does it reject?

Comment: Actually resource.id == null must always be false. Because if resource is available than an id must also be available. I just wanted to point out that both null check and non-null check are false at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got solved on its own. There might have been a temporary problem on firebase end. Now if resource is available null check always returns false, not null check always returns true for id field. Plus this one also returns always true if resource is available

```
match /{collectionName}/{document} {
        allow read: resource.id == document
        allow write: if false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasted so much time trying `request.resource.id == document`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using `{document}` instead of writing a nested rule with `{document=**}` and using `$(document)` as a parameter. But I don't want that. I want to use `resource.id` field

To use this a field as a validation you can use `resource.data.FIELDNAME`